# How to configure Oozie coordinator dataset for previous day

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to run workflow based on availability of Control files for previous date. Date format in my directory is `${basePath}/YYYYMMdd/00/_Complete`. I want to check the `_Complete` file inside my `00`. My Job will run daily on the previous day data. I tried the options provided in similar questions But still not working. When I am testing it for same day data with below value for instance , it is working but not with `(-1)` option. Is there any restriction on `URI-TEMPLATE` formats, meaning do we need to have it in fixed format  `path/${YEAR}${$MONTH}${DAY}/Complete`
Please help.

```
<instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
```

Here is the dryrun output for my Coordinator job.

```
    ***coordJob after parsing: ***
<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1" name="my_Scheduler_5f" frequency="1" start="2016-08-17T23:40Z" end="2016-08-19T23:45Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles" freq_timeunit="DAY" end_of_duration="NONE">
  <controls>
    <timeout>30</timeout>
  </controls>
  <input-events>
    <data-in name="coordInput_1" dataset="input1">
      <dataset name="input1" frequency="1" initial-instance="2016-08-17T00:00Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles" freq_timeunit="DAY" end_of_duration="NONE">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/myHdfsPath/Finalpath1/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}/00/</uri-template>
        <done-flag>_Complete</done-flag>
      </dataset>
      <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
    </data-in>
    <data-in name="coordInput_2" dataset="input2">
      <dataset name="input2" frequency="1" initial-instance="2016-08-17T23:00Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles" freq_timeunit="DAY" end_of_duration="NONE">
        <uri-template>${nameNode}/myHdfsPath/Finalpath2/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}/00/</uri-template>
        <done-flag>_Complete</done-flag>
      </dataset>
      <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
    </data-in>
  </input-events>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${nameNode}/myHdfsPath/My_POC/wf-app-dir</app-path>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>date</name>
          <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:actualTime(),-1,'DAY'), "yyyyMMdd")}</value>
        </property>
    </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
***actions for instance***
```

Comment: any progress on this ? Even I am facing similar issues

Comment: I didn't get any out of box solution for this. So I did a work around by adding 1 more simple java action to check the availability of the inputs which checks on the given input datapath list / date. Its not best but solved my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my job to look for the right `_Complete` flag using separate `<datasets>` and `<input-events>`.

```
<datasets>
  <dataset name="input1" frequency="1" initial-instance="2016-08-17T00:00Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles" freq_timeunit="DAY" end_of_duration="NONE">
    <uri-template>${nameNode}/myHdfsPath/Finalpath1/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}/00/</uri-template>
    <done-flag>_Complete</done-flag>
  </dataset>
  ... input2 ...
</datasets>

<input-events>
  <data-in name="coordInput_1" dataset="input1">
    <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
  </data-in>
  ... coordInput_2 ...
</input-events>
```

`current(-1)` is the part which specifies yesterday (for a daily dataset). In my case, the problem was that I'd copied an example with `current(0)`.